# Move SharePoint application between servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, administration

I have a MS Search Server 2010 application in a development server and want to move it to a live environment. Currently all services & the databases reside on one server. I want to use a dedicated SQL server for the database parts and have the web stuff on another server.

This is moving from a subdomain to a main domain - will that cause any issues? ie; dev.domain.com to domain.com.

Is there anything I need to look out for or make sure I do to ensure that this works properly?

Thanks

Comment: Since you can just recrawl all the content, what parts do you want to "move" just the configuration, or more?

Comment: Just the configuration I guess. Federated Search settings, design/style etc

Comment: ...and you want to stay with Search Server or mover to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I'll stay with search server, it seems to work better for my needs! Unless SharePoint offers something better in terms of searching network shares

Comment: Oh, boy, there's a thread starter. The short answer is: "No...but" :) Specifically in SharePoint 2013/2016 there is nothing "new" for crawling file shares...but...everything that comes after crawling is new. You get so much more control over the entire search experience. I'd look at the licensing costs and decide if it's worth the change.

Comment: Worth looking at the foundation versions at all?

Comment: Not if you want a real Search experience in 2013. Foundation is NLA in 2016.

Comment: I literally only want the file share searching though tbh, there are many other solutions in place for other SharePoint functionality

Comment: Foundation cannot crawl file shares.

Comment: In that case I'll see what I can do about obtaining a licence. Thanks for your help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't have any experience with MSS beyond the SharePoint components. Having said that you SHOULD be able to just create a new installation on your target and then "upgrade" or "attach" the existing databases from the previous installation. I'd look for info on doing a 2008 to 2010 "upgrade" and follow the guidance. (This is how we'd do it with SharePoint and it's the same underlying bits, though the version numbers are different.)